# (Python) Delete consecutive spaces in filename; leave a single space

Tags: python, rename, filenames, spaces

1.st step: underscore to space

```
path = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
os.rename(os.path.join(path,filename),os.path.join(path, filename.replace("_", " ")))
```

OUTCOME:

(cant post picture yet.. so:)

```
WKN_855681(INTEL_CORP._______DL-001)_vom_03.12.2018482523.pdf

Geändert auf: (changed to)

WKN 855681(INTEL CORP.       DL-001) vom 03.12.2018482523.pdf
```

!This is fine :D

now i like to delete the surplus spaces in the (changed to) state.

PS: im a bloody rookie so please dont kill me yet.

ty

Outcome, I think the text here doesn't show the spaces..?
[image: outcome, i think the text here doesnt show the spaces..?]

SOLVED STATE: 
[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific question or error when you execute ***delete the surplus space***?

Comment: To delete the surplus spaces i tried the following: path = os.getcwd()
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace(" ", "")))  >>>>>so i tried to replace a space with nothing. that worked. but i have no idea how to delete only the spaces that are consecutive. the spaces betwenn the words i like to keep. Desired outcome: WKN 855681(INTEL CORP. DL-001) vom 03.12.2018482523.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to replace the surplus spaces to just one

```
import re
re.sub('\s{1,}',' ',file)
```

Test

```
a='WKN 855681(INTEL CORP.       DL-001) vom 03.12.2018482523.pdf'
```

**output**

```
'WKN 855681(INTEL CORP. DL-001) vom 03.12.2018482523.pdf'
```

Or in a single step replace surplus `_` with just one space

```
re.sub('\_{1,}',' ',file)
```

Test

```
a='WKN_855681(INTEL_CORP._______DL-001)_vom_03.12.2018482523.pdf'
re.sub('\_{1,}',' ',a)
```

**Output**

```
'WKN 855681(INTEL CORP. DL-001) vom 03.12.2018482523.pdf'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression:

```
import re
os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, re.sub('[\s_]+', ' ', filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2c using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename):

```
import glob, os, re
for fn in glob.glob('C:\\somedir\\*'):
    new_fn = re.sub(" ", "_")
    os.rename(fn, new_fn)
```